# How to convert PDf with layers to PSD?

Tags: pdf, photoshop, psd

I would like to convert pdf with layers to psd file (photoshop), each layer in the pdf should be converted to layer in the psd. Any one familiar of how to accomplish in c#/javascript/python?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how to achieve that using c#/javascript/python

But it can be done using some designing tools 
Open the PDF in Illustrator  by default it will be in one layer only 
but you can distribute and object or content in different layers, once all layers are set you can export that file as PSD and use photoshop to open that PSD

Hope that would work !!

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I have to do it on large amount of files so I need to do it programmatically.